# Возможно ли сделать несколько IP "внешними" на VPS?

Tags: php, postgresql, ip, vps

Имеется VPS на Debian, на VPS расположены 5 сайтов, и под каждый из них куплен выделенный IP адрес. 
Никаких проблем связать один адрес с одним сайтом нет. Но появилась необходимость выполнять каждым из сайтов запросы на сторонний сервер, запросы в Postgres (при помощи PHP, pg_*), а идентификацию сторонний сервер выполняет как раз по IP адресу.

Собственно, пока выходит так, что все запросы на сторонний сервер идут с одного IP адреса, с которым изначально и приобретался VPS.

Вопрос. Есть ли техническая возможность выполнять запросы с каждого сайта таким образом, чтобы он IP определялся соответствующий, а не общий для всего VPS.

Купить под каждый сайт VPS это прекрасная идея, но мне пока не очень нравится =) Поэтому, прошу помощи :)

Результаты выполнения некоторых команд (реальные IP заменены на похожие)

```
user@dir:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.2/32 scope host venet0
    inet 37.140.10.240/32 brd 37.140.10.240 scope global venet0:0
    inet 37.140.10.20/32 brd 37.140.10.20 scope global venet0:1
    inet 95.180.5.75/32 brd 95.180.5.75 scope global venet0:2
```

и

```
user@dir:~# ip r
default dev venet0  scope link
```

и

```
user@dir:~# ls  /sys/class/net/
lo  venet0
```

Comment: с таким типом назначения адресов простым SNAT. бывает на разные интерфейсы ip выдают - там мучайся с таблицами маршрутизации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуй, добавлю ответ на свой же вопрос. В результате экспериментов и при помощи подсказок @eri было выработано следующее решение:

Установить apache2-mpm-itk

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk
```

Создать пользователя web-user1, группа web-user1

```
groupadd web-user1
useradd -G web-user1 web-user1
```

Назначить права на директорию с сайтом для этого пользователя

```
chown -R web-user1:web-user1 /var/www/html/project
```

Проверка, что поддерживается mpm_itk_module:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep mpm
```

В конфиг виртхоста добавить строки (конфиг apache вашего сайта, если говорить проще):

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId web-user1 web-user1 
</IfModule>
```

Ребут apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Добавить в iptables (выполнить в консоли):

```
USER_ID=$(id -u web-user1)
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner ${USER_ID} -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x
```

где `${USER_ID}` - id пользователя можно найти в `/etc/passwd` (описан как :user_id:group_id:, нужно значение из user_id) или получить командой `id -u username`

x.x.x.x - IP адрес, с которого должны отправляться запросы

0x2 - уникальная маркировка. Для каждого сайта своя (0x2, 0x3 и тп)

Для сохранения правил фаервола (debian):

```
apt install iptables-persistent
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Но если стоит другой фаервол вроде firewalld или ufw - настройки делать и сохранять нужно в них.

Comment: А правила добавил в iptables-persistent(самый простой) или firewald(centos) или в какой-нибудь фаерволл?

Comment: @eri я просто в консоли выполнил эти команды) Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: надо сохраняться

Answer (score 1):

Запускаем каждый сайт от имени отдельного пользователя. Маркируешь трафик в [iptables](/questions/tagged/iptables) по владельцу процесса. Например, user2 имеет `uid=1003` (смотрим в /etc/passwd, env)

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1003  -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1003  -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Ставим метку 2 на соединение, а дальше типовая настройка или с `SNAT` или с несколькими таблицами маршрутов.

Comment: Сейчас попробую! К сожалению, я больше в php/js силен, чем в сетевых технологиях. Верна ли следующая настройка SNAT: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o eth0.1 -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4 , где 1.2.3.4 - мой дополнительный IP адрес а eth0.1 его интерфейс? Кстати, в interfaces интерфейсы прописаны как venet0:x, это стоит отобразить в указанном мной запросе вместо eth?

Comment: интерфейсы надо отображать так, как они выглядят в /sys/class/net/

Comment: Нет, у тебя одним SNAT так не выйдет. надо по маркировке. 
Может вечеромнапишу более полный пример.

напиши что покажет `ip a ` и `ip  r `

Comment: В первом посте выложил результаты вывода

Comment: Получилось. Респект тебе и уважуха. Добавил развернутый ответ ниже..

Comment: eri, я тут выяснил, что мой чудо-метод работает только до перезагрузки VPS. После - почему-то слетает. Так и должно происходить? Если да, можно ли это как-то "зафиксировать"?